# java.lang.ClassCastException in tomcat server logs when running webservices with AXIS2

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, classcastexception

I have written a webservice it works perfectly fine on the UI and all the Unit tests are passing.
 I am able to send the request and response to and from Webservice.

But when I check the server log I get to see this kind of stack trace.
 Has any one seen this exception earlier?

I am using AXIS2, Java 6,and tomcat 6.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOnlyMessageReceiver cannot be cast to org.apache.axis2.engine.MessageReceiver
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.loadMessageReceiver(DescriptionBuilder.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder$1.run(DescriptionBuilder.java:145)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.processMessageReceivers(DescriptionBuilder.java:141)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:102)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:641)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.<init>(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:157)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:516)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:436)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when the classes are loaded from different classloaders.

Make sure there is only a single axis2 JAR on the classpath and that your app can't see Axis2 JARs from other apps on the same server.